# Pull all the fields from both tables in Laravel Many-to-Many relationships

Tags: php, laravel

Please any help me that how i pull all the fields from both tables in laravel many to many relationship.
I have two table

**categories**

- id
- cname
- ctitle
- description

**products**

- id
- pname
- ptitle
- pdescription
- price

and bridge table

**products_to_categories**

- id
- category_id
- product_id

So i have pull all the fields from both tables based on product id.

Comment: Post your tried code

Answer (score 1):

UPD: As commented patricus, the "bridge" table should be called "category_product"

First, you should define the "belongsToMany" relationship in the Product model:

```
// ...
class Product extends Eloquent {
    // ...
    function categories() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
    }
}
```

After it you should load the product by id:

```
$product = Product::find($product_id);
```

And now you can access its categories through the "categories" property:

```
foreach($product->categories as $category) 
{
    // do what you want with the $category
}
```

Official docs for M2M relationships:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: I think it will be only pull the categories table fields but how i pull the products table fields?

Comment: All products table fields are in the `$product` variable. You can acces them as properties of this object. I.e. `$product->title`, `$product->description`

Comment: The laravel convention for the pivot table is alphabetical, so it would be category_product. Also, if you don't want to rename the table, you can pass the name of the pivot table in as the second parameter in the belongsToMany method.